# Concatenating fields when BREAK ON command is used

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, string-aggregation

I have built a command that uses the BREAK ON command to stop the output of duplicate field names. For example:

```
f.name | f.value
f.name | f.value
f.name | f.value
```

becomes:

```
f.name | f.value
       | f.value
       | f.value
```

Is there any way to have this output as:

```
f.name | f.value,f.value,f.value
```

In some instances the f.name field with have over 20 f.values associated with it.

The output will eventually be used to import into other places so I am trying to make the output as friendly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You're not looking for a SQL*Plus command, you're looking for a string aggregation.

Assuming your current query is:

```
select name, value from my_table
```

you can change it as follows to get your desired result. The DISTINCT is included to eliminate duplicate results in your list.

```
select name, listagg(value, ', ') within group (order by value) as value
  from ( select distinct name, value from my_table )
 group by name
```

[LISTAGG()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) was only released in 11.2, if you're using an earlier version of Oracle you could use the undocumented function WM_CONCAT() or the user defined function STRAGG() as outlined in [this useful page on string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).